# Rikulo Bootjack + PolymerDart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, rikulo, bootjack

I'm trying to use the excellent [Bootjack](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bootjack) library with [PolymerDart](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/), and although the CSS theming is working, the dart code isn't executing in the Polymer component.

I've created a dead simple test showing the problem. You'll see the raw html version works fine, but the shadow DOM version doesn't.

[Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/shanestevens/60d39f648f5b6e68d396). Just download as a zip, it has everything to *not* work ;)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-- Update --
After TinyFox's advice of directly wiring up the control, it now *half* works. I've updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/shanestevens/60d39f648f5b6e68d396) with the change.

-- Shane

Answer (score 3):

The code is not executed because the way you include the main.dart file is outdated.

use

```html
<script type="application/dart">export "main.dart";</script>
```

The dropdown still doesn't work probably because

```dart
..on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', _toggleEvent, selector: _TOGGLE_SELECTOR)
```

in packages/bootjack/src/dropdown.dart
where _TOGGLE_SELECTOR is (same file)

```dart
static const String _TOGGLE_SELECTOR ='[data-toggle=dropdown]';
```

isn't working as expected. 
I guess the selector doesn't find elements inside a polymer element even if you have set `applyAuthorStyles` to true.

Comment: The same thing should apply to Bootstrap w/ Polymer.js. In Bootstrap, to initialize Dropdown, click events are listened at document level via jQuery against selector '[data-toggle=dropdown]'. But in [Shadow DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#event-retargeting), an event bubbled out from shadow will have its event target replaced by the host element, causing the selector to miss. Bootjack & DQuery follow the exact implementation & spec of Bootstrap & jQuery, which possibly explains.

Comment: It does seem as though the selector query isn't making it into the Shadow DOM. So I tried TinyFox's idea and it sort of worked...

Answer (score 1):

zoechi's answer and my comment explains the possible cause of the problem.

To work it around, you can try to [wire](http://api.rikulo.org/bootjack/latest/bootjack/Dropdown.html) the element manually inside your shadow DOM, and it should be able to handle the click event by itself.

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried wiring it up directly, and now the dropdown drops down, but doesn't close on a second press, even though the toggle function is called (I traced it). It looks like the Shadow DOM is really messing things up for me :(